# Notifications not showing up properly in Slack and other Electron apps

Tags: 16.04, notification, electron

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04. Every this is working fine but I am not getting slack notification properly. I am getting slack notification like alert box like shown in below picture.

[image]

Before this it appears upper right corner as shown in below picture.

[image]

Can any one help me to resolve this problem.?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Following solution works for me

Run this command

> sudo touch /usr/lib/libunity-electron_notification_fix

After this, restart software whose notification are not working fine (Slack in my case). If still you are not getting notification properly, restart you system.

See this bug report, it is fixed in Electron but applications will need to be updated over time:

- https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/465